# why I must to call the `getchar()` additional?

Tags: c

```
/* C89 */
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int c;  
    printf("Print any not EOF char: ");
    c = getchar(); /* I put a char and press 
                   the ENTER key here.*/
    printf("int value: %d\n", c);   
    printf("Now print the EOF char \n(Ctrl + Z for Windows, " 
        "or Ctrl + D for Linux): ");    
    c = getchar(); 
    EOF == c ? printf("You did it! int value: %d\n", c) : 
        printf("It is not EOF char!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I press the 'a' key and press ENTER, I get this:
Output:

> Print any not EOF char: a int value: 97 Now print the EOF char (Ctrl +
>   Z for Windows, or Ctrl + D for Linux): It is not EOF char!

So this is not asked me the char in the second call of getchar(). Why?

If I press the 'a' char and CTRL + Z (I use Windows OS), I get this:
Output:

> Print any not EOF char: a^Z int value: 97 Now print the EOF char (Ctrl
>   + Z for Windows, or Ctrl + D for Linux): It is not EOF char!

But the Ctrl + Z is EOF for Windows OS. Why this happened?

If I modify my code:

```
/* C89 */
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int c;  
    printf("Print any not EOF char: ");
    c = getchar(); /* I put a char and press 
                   the ENTER key here.*/
    printf("int value: %d\n", c);   
    printf("Now print the EOF char \n(Ctrl + Z for Windows, " 
        "or Ctrl + D for Linux): ");
    getchar(); /* Ignore the ENTER key pressed before. */
    c = getchar(); /* Now I can to ask next char. */
    EOF == c ? printf("You did it! int value: %d\n", c) : 
        printf("It is not EOF char!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Now output is what I expected:
Output:

> Print any not EOF char: a int value: 97 Now print the EOF char (Ctrl +
>   Z for Windows, or Ctrl + D for Linux): ^Z You did it! int value: -1

Why this happened? I.e. why I must to call the `getchar()` additional?

Comment: Didn't you answer this yourself in the comment? `getchar(); /* Ignore the ENTER key pressed before. */`

Comment: No. Why don't working the next input: `a^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z`? I get this:
Print any not EOF char: a^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z
int value: 97
Now print the EOF char
(Ctrl + Z for Windows, or Ctrl + D for Linux):

Comment: Enter is a char too.

Comment: EOF is a char too, as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the Enter key does two things: adds a NewLine character (ASCII NL, code 10) at the end of input buffer and then flushes it, making the whole line available to your `getchar()`. So after pressing 'a' you need to press Enter also, so that your program can see and interpret 'a'. However then you must skip NL character from the input stream with additional `getchar()`.

However as you know what the next request will be, you can press 'a' (entering 'a'), CTRL+Z (entering EOF character) and then Enter (entering NL and sending 3 characters for processing) – then the two characters 'a' and EOF could be read by two `getchar`s.